# Return null records as "0" in a dupe check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing data quality rules, and in this case- am looking to return duplicate values for the column called "ID". The problem is that, when there are no duplicates, null is returned instead of 0. I need 0 to be returned for the non-dupes. I've tried putting the ISNULL near the SELECT ID and SELECT COUNT(ID) statements, but have had no success. I simply can't figure out how where to put the ISNULL statement(if that's accurate to even use), or if COALESCE should be used, or if I need an outer join(according to a similar question). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT
 CAST('DQR_ID_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DQR_ID
 CAST('DB_NAME_HERE') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DB_NAME
 CAST('ID') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS COLUMN_TO_DUPE_CHECK
 SUM (DEFECT.DEFECT_COUNT) AS DEFECT_COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
      ID,
      COUNT(ID) AS DEFECT_COUNT
    FROM DB_NAME_HERE
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING (COUNT(ID)) > 1
) AS DEFECT
```

Comment: You just need `ISNULL(SUM (DEFECT.DEFECT_COUNT), 0)`. Side note: `COUNT(someNonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`

Comment: @Charlieface I think SUM (ISNULL(DEFECT.DEFECT_COUNT,0)) better - in your statement if one of the rows will be null, all result will be 0, no?

Comment: @LevGelman No because if there are no rows then you will still get `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place `ISNULL` around the `SUM`

```sql
ISNULL(SUM (DEFECT.DEFECT_COUNT), 0)
```

Do not place `ISNULL` *inside* the `SUM`, because then you will still get `NULL` if there are no rows to sum.